# PHP and online payments

Tags: php, e-commerce

Is there any php tutorials online that can show me how to build my own php shopping cart and payment system for paying for digital goods without having to use PayPal or any other online payment system. So basically what I'm trying to say I guess is there a way that I can build my own payment service using PHP?

Answer (score 1):

Unless its really critical that you create your own payment system for business reasons, you are probably better off using a pre-built payment system or an e-commerce library (of which there are many both commerical and free), that already has had other programmers work out the bugs and security problems that arise when dealing with taking payments online.

There is a good list of Open Source PHP Shopping Cart solutions [on this blog post](http://twit88.com/blog/2007/10/18/open-source-php-e-commerce-solutions/).